# Format cell if all the cells in a row are not empty

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-arrayformula

I tried all kind of formula but they all seem to work the other way around for me. I have a very large sheet with lots of columns. I'd like to have the first cell in the row to be a certain color if any of the cells in that row is empty. Basically, a warning saying not all the cells have value.

The first step, I'm trying to make it work just for one row for now and I'm stuck.
Let say for row 2, format cell A2 in red if any of the cells in the range is empty. I tried

```
=len(join("", B2:ZZ2))
```

---

```
=$B2=""
```

---

```
=NOT(ISBLANK(B2:ZZ2))
```

It's not working!  It's getting red even if only one cell as something in it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found a very simple answer. =COUNTBLANK() and it's working.

Thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B1:Z="", "♦")), , 999^99)), "♦")="♦", 1))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNA(IF(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B1:Z="", "♦")), , 999^99)), "♦")="♦", 1)),1))
```

[image: 0]